# How to filter scipy spars matrix's nodes based on the average degree in Python?

Tags: python, sparse-matrix, networkx, social-networking, adjacency-matrix

I am using the Flickr social network data and trying to reduce the size by filtering the dataset (number of nodes) based on degree.I would like to work only with the top 50 nodes that have the highest degree. After creating a list of top 50 nodes with highest degree I am unable to apply to the original graph.

dataset source: 
http://networkrepository.com/soc-flickr.php

My current code:

```py
import networkx as nx
from networkx import from_scipy_sparse_matrix as sm
from scipy import io

flickr = io.mmread(os.path.join('soc-flickr','soc-flickr.mtx'))
Gflickr = sm(flicker)

print (nx.info(Gflickr))
# Out: Type: Graph
# Out: Number of nodes: 513969
# Out: Number of edges: 3190452
# Out: Average degree:  12.4150

for n, d in Gflickr.degree():
    print('%s %d' % (n, d))

top_50 = sorted(Gflickr.degree, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
top_50 = top_50[:50]
top_50
Out: [(9205, 4369),
 (3843, 4196),
 (1552, 4011),
 (75, 4004),
 (1641, 3810),
 (5814, 3779),....

# took the first item from the lists, which should be 
the index of the node in the original graph

node_index_list = [item[0] for item in top_50]
S = nx.to_scipy_sparse_matrix(Gflickr, nodelist= [9205,3843,1552,75,6517,11816,....,42004,109870,70193,30540])

#create a graph from the sparse matrix
top_50_graph =sm(S)
print(nx.info(top_50_graph))


# here is the issue...
Out: Type: Graph
Number of nodes: 50
Number of edges: 0
Average degree:   0.0000
```

Answer (score 1):

You can determine the highest degree nodes with the following code:

```py
import networkx as nx

graph = nx.karate_club_graph()

number_of_nodes = 10
top_nodes = list(sorted(list(graph.nodes), key=lambda x: graph.degree(x), reverse=True))[:number_of_nodes]
print(top_nodes)
# [33, 0, 32, 2, 1, 3, 31, 8, 13, 23]
print([graph.degree(node) for node in top_nodes])
# [17, 16, 12, 10, 9, 6, 6, 5, 5, 5]
```

I'm not sure, if the graph of the 50 highest degree nodes (especially after already filtering some edges(?) before), preserves that much properties of the original graph.

Comment: Thanks @Sparky05.I managed to use something similar filtering, however unable to use the filtered nodes on the original graph.

Comment: Are you looking for a [subgraph](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/classes/generated/networkx.Graph.subgraph.html)?